# Supress \cleardoublepage for some chapters

Tags: table-of-contents, page-breaking

I am using `book` environment.

Between `\listoffigures`, `\listoftables`, `\printglossary[glossaryname]`s and appendices, I need a normal `\clearpage` between them (not a `\cleardoublepage`).

I still need to define these as `chapter`s for document style consistensy and `\cleardoublepage` between normal `chapter`s.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try

```
\begingroup
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\listoftables
\endgroup
```

Comment: short, fast, precise and does the trick. Thanks